# Finding the sum of the multiples of 3 between 1 and 1000 with filter and reduce

Tags: javascript

```
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) list.push(i);
var result = list.filter(element => element % 3 == 0); 
list.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator + value);
console.log(result);
```

This is my code so far, I need to get it all in one line in the result object but when I run the code it doesn't add up the elements, it only runs the filter part and not the reduce. How can I get it to do both?

Comment: Just like `.filter()`, `.reduce()` **returns** a value. Your code ignores that.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring reduce method result. Same as `filter`, `reduce` returns a value:

```
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) list.push(i);
var result = list
           .filter(element => element % 3 == 0)
           .reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator + value);
console.log(result); //166833
```

Comment: Thank you. Silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below one

```
  var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) list.push(i);
    var output = list
               .filter(element => element % 3 == 0)
               .reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator + value);
    console.log(output);
```